# How can whole tone melodies sound more interesting?

Tags: theory, melody

How can one make melodies made from whole tone scales sound more interesting & appealing? Unlike melodies based in a certain mode or a key, whole tone scales use only tones as the intervals. This is something which our ears are not normally attuned to. How do I write whole tone melodies more better?

Comment: They do sound interesting if done well but more intiguing and out of place usually. However, in place of a long melody, shorter riffs on electric guitars and bass, that are whole tone sound great especially in the right songs.

Answer (score 9):

*This is more of an extended comment as opposed to an answer.*

Whole tone scales are difficult because they do seem to wear out their uniqueness quickly, for whatever reason (I'm not so sure why).

General tip for learning composition: find works that make use of the material you want to know better and internalize them, analyze them, and try to understand them from your own point of view. Take a look at these two pieces:

Both of these composers are, of course, absolute giants, but you'll notice that nobody really can just stay in a single whole-tone scale, and have to juxtapose it against other sounds or other whole tone scales. I'm not so sure why this is (perhaps it's *too* symmetrical to create sufficient variation?), so it is often juxtaposed against other scales or melodic/harmonic material. See the following for a very good example of this:

The A section of this tune is heavily whole-tone, juxtaposed against other harmonies in the B section for contrast (and release). All this being said, you might have to add contrast to make your whole tone melodies more salient and listenable.

Comment: As a slightly different example, Bartok's 10 Easy Piano Pieces, BB 51: IX.  It constantly shifts between the two different whole tone scales (i.e. ignoring any root note, one is a half-step offset from the other) rather than relying on as much juxtaposition.  However the whole tone scales are used more as a texture and the melody played over them is not always whole tone (for instance you can hear major sevenths at one point)

Answer (score 1):

As the given examples show the whole tone scale can't be made much more interesting. The exciting  element is the rhythm!

I don't know why Bartok and Debussy are stuck  to the scale lines, could be in respect to the performers who maybe beginners). I also used whole tone lines in a V7b5 chord and  only once in a quartet as in parallels of thirds. If I knew  a better answer I wouldn't tell it as I would like to keep this secret like a cooking recept for myself.

Comment: Hahaha good one!